# How do Schubert classes form a basis for $H^{*}(Gr(k, n))$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra

I've gone through many texts in algebraic geometry, specifically, Schubert calculus. They all claim that the Schubert classes $[\Omega_{\lambda}]$ form a basis for the cohomology ring of the complex Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $n$-dimensional complex space, i.e. $H^{*}(Gr(k, n))$, but without any proof. I would think that there could be a way to somehow show this result using an argument involving linear independence and span, but I'm not sure where to begin. In the back of Fulton's $\textit{Young tableaux}$, it is suggested to construct a filtration $$Gr(k, n)=Y_0 \supset Y_1 \supset \cdots,$$ where $Y_p$ is the union of all Schubert varieties $\Omega_{\lambda}$ with $|\lambda| \geq p$. Then I would have to take the cohomology of each member of the filtration, but how does one conclude that the Schubert classes form a basis of the cohomology ring in question?

Comment: Since you're asking a topological question (not, say, about Chow groups), it's unlikely to be given an answer with the details you want in an algebraic geometry or combinatorics book. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology and use the fact that each $Y_p \setminus Y_{p-1}$ is even-real-dimensional to see that the boundary maps vanish.

Comment: A different way to start getting a handle on this is to read the example given in Griffiths and Harris for $\CC$. It is done with matrices which I found more approachable to start with.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Even-real-dimensional comes from the fact that complex space has twice the dimension of real space, correct?

Comment: Yup$ \!\!\! \! $

Comment: @B.Bischof: Which chapter in Griffiths and Harris has the matrix example?

Comment: Some references are given beginning on page 1078 of Kleiman and Laksov's survey http://math.ucr.edu/~jdolan/schubert1.pdf.

Comment: When I studied this subject, I found this text very useful: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jblasiak/grassmannian.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Fulton is suggesting is (an easy special case of) the fact that cellular and usual cohomology are equal.  Consider the long exact sequence attached to the pair $(Y_p,Y_{p-1})$.  We have maps
$$ \cdots \to H^*(Y_{p}, Y_{p-1}; \mathbb Z)\to H^*(Y_p; \mathbb Z) \to H^*(Y_{p-1}; \mathbb Z) \to \cdots.$$

The key observation is that $Y_{p}$ with $Y_{p-1}$ smashed to a point is a wedge of $2p$ dimensional spheres, one for each Schubert cell of dimension $p$.   Thus  $H^i(Y_{p}, Y_{p-1}; \mathbb Z)$ is only non-zero for $i=2p$, and that degree is the free abelian group on the Schubert classes in dimension $p$.  Now, induct on dimension, and the result follows.

Comment: By usual do you mean simplicial?

Comment: He probably means singular (co)homology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology

Comment: @Libertron All I used was the Eilenrod-Steenrod axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms), so any cohomology theory satisfying those (such as singular cohomology) would work.